# Schwarz lemma and Maximum Modulus Principle?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let f be a holomorphic function in $\mathbb{D}$ and $a \in \mathbb{D}$ such that $|f(z)| < 1$ for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$ and $f(a)=f(-a)=0$. Show that $|f(0)| \leq |a|^2$. What can we conclude if this holds with equality?

I have tried using schwarz pick and max modulus theorem but to no avail. Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: With $T_a(z) = \frac{z-a}{1-\bar{a}z}$ (being a linear fractional transformation of the unit disk mapping $a$ to $0$), consider the map $g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{T_a(z) T_{-a}(z)}$.